# Ruby's Twitter REST api not working

Tags: ruby, twitter

I am trying to use the ruby interface for [twitter api](https://github.com/sferik/twitter).The Streaming Api is working but Rest spi is not.

Code :

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'twitter'

client = Twitter::REST::Client.new do |config|
  # you must set up an application using Twitter's developer site, and set these values:
  # (See the Configuration example)
  config.consumer_key        = "xxx"
  config.consumer_secret     = "xxx"
  config.access_token        = "xxx-xxx"
  config.access_token_secret = "xxx"
end

puts client.user('xyz')
```

I am always getting the following error -

```
Faraday::Builder is now Faraday::RackBuilder.
/home/atul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/twitter-5.5.1/lib/twitter/rest/client.rb:143:in `rescue in request': execution expired (Twitter::Error)
from /home/atul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/twitter-5.5.1/lib/twitter/rest/client.rb:131:in `request'
from /home/atul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/twitter-5.5.1/lib/twitter/rest/client.rb:97:in `get'
from /home/atul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/twitter-5.5.1/lib/twitter/rest/api/utils.rb:118:in `object_from_response'
from /home/atul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/twitter-5.5.1/lib/twitter/rest/api/users.rb:257:in `user'
from actresses.rb:17:in `<main>'
```

I am trying to increase the time out because of [this](https://github.com/sferik/twitter/issues/401) solution but am able to figure out how to do that.
I don't understand what am I doing wrong as the same code is working for Streaming api after making the appropriate changes.

Comment: @Casey I tried to add twitter-api tag but for some strange reasons I was not able to.

Comment: That's crazy - I approved @jmromer's edit, and added [tag:twitter-api] manually because I noticed it was absent despite him claiming to have added it in the edit comment. The tag must be broken somehow?

Comment: It seems that [tag:twitter-api] is set as a synonym of [tag:twitter], so it is automatically replaced ([see here](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/twitter/synonyms)).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely clear on what kind of an issue you're having, but to set the timeout you may want to try

```
custom_options = Twitter::Default::CONNECTION_OPTIONS.merge(
                          request: { open_timeout: 5, timeout: 20 } )  # default timeout is 10

client = Twitter::REST::Client.new do |config|
  # you must set up an application using Twitter's developer site, and set these values:
  # (See the Configuration example)
  config.consumer_key        = "xxx"
  config.consumer_secret     = "xxx"
  config.access_token        = "xxx-xxx"
  config.access_token_secret = "xxx"
  config.connection_options  = custom_options
end
```

I'm not sure if that will resolve that error, though.

Comment: @ jmromer Hi. Thanks for the reply. But it doesn't work. Same error again. I am fed up now. All I need to do is to use ruby for twitter API and get the accounts of some users. I need to check whether these accounts are verified or not. But I can't even use the API. I am using ruby 1.8.7 and Rails 2.3.14 (if you need to know.). I have been trying to this for last 24 hours :(. I have never used ruby before. I hope you understand my frustration and can help me. :)

Comment: the issue appears to be specific to 1.8.7: http://j.mp/1haYx1U
It may be overkill in your case, but I'd install rvm and the latest version of ruby.

Comment: I just found out that streaming API is working fine. I am problem with REST api.