# Tweepy user_search api is very slow

Tags: twitter, tweepy

After two days of unsuccessful attempt to use twitter gem I have decided to use tweepy of python for a task. (My original attempt was with ruby and I posted the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21067974/rubys-twitter-rest-api-not-working))

My task is to collect all those actresses who have a verified account on twitter. I have taken the list of actresses from wikipedia.
Everything looks fine till now. I have started hitting twitter REST api with each name and I check whether it is a verified account or not.
The only problem I have is that the response is very slow. It takes about 12-15 seconds for every request. Am I doing something wrong here or is it how it is suppose to be.

Below is my code in its entirety :

```
import tweepy

consumer_key = 'xxx'
consumer_secret = 'xxx'

access_token_key = 'xx-xx'
access_token_secret = 'xxx'

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token_key, access_token_secret)

api = tweepy.API(auth)

actresses = []
f = open('final','r')
for line in f:
  actresses.append(line)

f.close()
print actresses

for actress in actresses:
  print actress
  users = api.search_users(actress)
  for u in users:
    if u.verified == True and u.name == actress:
      print u.name + "   ===   https://twitter.com/" + u.screen_name
```

Also is there any better way to extract the verified actresses using that list?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is no faster way to do it, given that you only know the actresses' full names, and not their screen names. Each request will take a long time, as Twitter needs to return the results of users matching the query (there may be quite a few). Each one needs to be loaded and examined, which can take a while, depending on how many results were returned.